# Error "Debuggee returned error code 200" when debugging Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: debugging, xamarin

I've suddenly started getting the above error when I create breakpoints in my code.

This appears in a dialog box, and when I OK the dialog box, the app sticks on the breakpoint in question and doesn't proceed. If I delete the breakpoint, the app still sticks on the breakpointed line.

The only thing I've changed is to update my FreshMvvm package (it's a Xamarin.Forms app), which brings in a load of .net standard libraries and uses Rx to create weak event bindings.

This is killing my development - any known cause/solution? I see [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/26267/debuggee-returned-error-code-200) has previously been posted -but no solution.

This is on Visual Studio for Mac, and the app is on an Android device.

Version information:

=== Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac ===

Version 7.1.5 (build 2)
Installation UUID: 650b4c91-c7f5-4ee5-ad70-6f178f314906
Runtime:
    Mono 5.2.0.224 (d15-3/14f2c81) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

```
Package version: 502000224
```

=== NuGet ===

Version: 4.3.0.2418

=== .NET Core ===

Runtime: Not installed
SDK: Not installed
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.2.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Version: 1.5.5
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 8.0 (11246)
Build 8A218a

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 7.4.5.1 (Visual Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/jameslavery/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        2.3   (API level 10)
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
        4.1   (API level 16)
        4.3   (API level 18)
        4.4   (API level 19)
        5.0   (API level 21)
        5.1   (API level 22)
        6.0   (API level 23)
        7.0   (API level 24)
        7.1   (API level 25)

SDK Tools Version: 26.1.1
SDK Platform Tools Version: 26.0.0
SDK Build Tools Version: 26.0.2

Java SDK: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 10.12.3.3 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 8a391069
Branch: d15-3
Build date: 2017-08-28 16:51:11-0400

=== Xamarin Inspector ===

Version: 1.3.1
Hash: cbc48dd
Branch: 1.3-release
Build date: Thu, 21 Sep 2017 19:52:53 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 3.6.3.3 (Visual Studio Community)

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 701050002
Git revision: 7afedcaef8e7542e70e3cf8f9bdb26938b8c0876
Build date: 2017-09-15 08:39:58-04
Xamarin addins: 3262aadf811a18c12eac6742532d052b0139a808
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-d15-3-xcode9

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.11.6
Darwin 15.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0
    Thu Jun 23 18:25:34 PDT 2016
    root:xnu-3248.60.10~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

=== Enabled user installed addins ===

Redth's Addins 1.0.9